# RecyclerView/StaggeredGridLayoutManager: Force group of consecutive views into the same span/column

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, staggeredgridlayout

Currently, I'm using a RecyclerView to display a set of views with different view types, where a group of consecutive items belongs together: a header, a variable set of content items, and a separator/footer.
[image: Current situation]
Now I also want my UI to look good on bigger devices, aka use multiple panes, so I switched to a StaggeredGridLayoutManager. The problem here is that it spreads views evenly between all spans, means one group gets spread over multiple columns.
[image: Situation with staggered LayoutManager]
Thus, I would like to specify that the layout manager puts a consecutive set of views into the same span, and only then put the next group in the next one.
[image: What I want]
Is this somehow possible with the LayoutManager I use? Can I modify it to work like that without just duplicating and editing it? Support lib devs: are there any plans to introduce such behaviour?

Please tell me whether I should provide any other information, and when something isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired layout with the Support Library's `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`; you need to make each 'group' of items (e.g. header1 + 1-3 + footer) a single view returned by your adapter. This view could itself be a `RecyclerView`.

That is you'll have one outer `RecyclerView` with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and multiple inner `RecyclerView`s with `LinearLayoutManager`s. You can likely share a single `RecycledViewPool` between the inner RVs. You'll have to do some gymnastics to create appropriate adapters for the inner RVs but this is likely simpler than writing your own `LayoutManager`!!

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked very well, though I still have to work out some issues with my `CoordinatorLayout`, as it doesn't get the swipe feedback when you swipe on the child `RecyclerView`s. Also, I didn't know there was the option to share the view pool, very interesting!

Comment: EDIT: I realized I can just use `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. Nice!